# Python for loop doesn't have expected results

Tags: python

I got a bit stuck with a for loop - what I can see it is doing appears correct but isn't exactly what I'm trying to accomplish with it. I've come from a C background but any advice here would be beneficial.

```
def deal(player_num, cards):
    a = 0
    z = 0
    i = 0
    b = 0
    c = player_num
    hand = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16]    
    for a in range(player_num):
        hand[a] = cards[i] + cards[i+b+c]
        b == b+1
        i == i+1
        z == z+1
    return hand
```

So the `for a in range(player_num)` seems to be working (appends `a++`) but `hand[0]`, `hand[1]`, etc. gets the same hand. I guess it loops a but not the other variables, so I need to use more than 1 nested loop to get `i++`, `b++` and `c++`?

Answer (score 6):

`b == b+1` is a logical expression (returning `False` every time), not an assignment.  I'm guessing you want something like:  `b += 1`

Comment: Since he wants `b++`, there isn't much debate, I'd say.

Comment: Ah perfect, thanks, so == doesn't assign, its only used to compare :)

Comment: Well ... there really is no equivalent to c's `++` operator in python since python integers are immutable.  But yeah.  I'm pretty sure this is what OP wants.

Comment: @user2127162 -- Precisely.

Answer (score 4):

`==` is the equality operator in Python. `=` is the assignment operator.

`==` checks whether its left operand and its right operand are equal and return True or False accordingly. `b` and `b+1` will never be equal to each other and either way it does not make sense to perform an operation without side-effect (like comparing two values for equality) and then do nothing with its result.

If you want to change the values of your variables, use the assignment operator `=` instead of `==`.

Comment: I suppose you could create a class such that `b == b + 1`, but that certainly isn't the case for integers.